# Can I handle imports in an Abstract Syntax Tree?

Tags: python, python-2.7, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to parse and check `config.py` for admissible nodes.
`config.py` can import other config files, which also must be checked.

Is there any functionality in the `ast` module to parse `ast.Import` and `ast.ImportFrom` objects to `ast.Module` objects?

Here is a code example, I am checking a configuration file (`path_to_config`), but I want to also check any files that it imports:

```
with open(path_to_config) as config_file:
    ast_tree = ast.parse(config_file.read())
    for script_object in ast_tree.body:
        if isinstance(script_object, ast.Import):
            # Imported file must be checked too
        elif isinstance(script_object, ast.ImportFrom):
            # Imported file must be checked too
        elif not _is_admissible_node(script_object):
            raise Exception("Config file '%s' contains unacceptable statements" % path_to_config)
```

Comment: take a look at [`ast.NodeTransformer` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer)

Comment: the problem is that i do not know how to import ast.Import obj with ast lib :(    I have an instance of "ast.Import" but i do not know how to parse it.

Comment: what do you want to do with it? find source file location (it's not always presented, e.g. for `C` extensions or dynamically created module)? or import it (may lead to undesired side-effects like removing files)?

Comment: Config file can import another config file. I need to check if config consists of admissible nodes. (Admissible in my case is ast.Import, ast.ImportFrom, ast.Assign, ast.If ) But config file may import another config file. and i need to check if imported file consists of admissible nodes. and so on. In my example i can check only one file "path_to_config", but i want to check files which main cfg imports too.

Comment: maybe there is another library for these task?

Comment: What is the goal here, to not actually import those modules, just find their source code? Then take into account that there is *no foolproof way* of finding all modules used in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little more complex than you think. `from foo import name` is a valid way of importing both an object defined in the `foo` module, and the `foo.name` module, so you may have to try *both* forms to see if they resolve to a file. Python also allows for aliases, where code can import `foo.bar`, but the actual module is really defined as `foo._bar_implementation` and made available as an attribute of the `foo` package. You can't detect all of these cases purely by looking at `Import` and `ImportFrom` nodes.

If you ignore those cases and only look at the `from` name, then you'll still have to turn the module name into a filename, then parse the source from the file, for each import.

In Python 2 you can use [`imp.find_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) to get an open file object for the module <sup>(*)</sup>. You want to keep the full module name around when parsing each module, because you'll need it to help you figure out package-relative imports later on. `imp.find_module()` can't handle package imports so I created a wrapper function:

```
import imp

_package_paths = {}
def find_module(module):
    # imp.find_module can't handle package paths, so we need to do this ourselves
    # returns an open file object, the filename, and a flag indicating if this
    # is a package directory with __init__.py file.
    path = None
    if '.' in module:
        # resolve the package path first
        parts = module.split('.')
        module = parts.pop()
        for i, part in enumerate(parts, 1):
            name = '.'.join(parts[:i])
            if name in _package_paths:
                path = [_package_paths[name]]
            else:
                _, filename, (_, _, type_) = imp.find_module(part, path)
                if type_ is not imp.PKG_DIRECTORY:
                    # no Python source code for this package, abort search
                    return None, None
                _package_paths[name] = filename
                path = [filename]
    source, filename, (_, _, type_) = imp.find_module(module, path)
    is_package = False
    if type_ is imp.PKG_DIRECTORY:
        # load __init__ file in package
        source, filename, (_, _, type_) = imp.find_module('__init__', [filename])
        is_package = True
    if type_ is not imp.PY_SOURCE:
        return None, None, False
    return source, filename, is_package
```

I'd also track what module names you already imported so you don't process them twice; use the name from the `spec` object to make sure you track their canonical names.

Use a stack to process all the modules:

```
with open(path_to_config) as config_file:
    # stack consists of (modulename, ast) tuples
    stack = [('', ast.parse(config_file.read()))]

seen = set()
while stack:
    modulename, ast_tree = stack.pop()
    for script_object in ast_tree.body:
        if isinstance(script_object, (ast.Import, ast.ImportFrom)):
            names = [a.name for a in script_object.names]
            from_names = []
            if hasattr(script_object, 'level'):  # ImportFrom
                from_names = names
                name = script_object.module
                if script_object.level:
                    package = modulename.rsplit('.', script_object.level - 1)[0]
                    if script_object.module:
                        name = "{}.{}".format(name, script_object.module)
                    else:
                        name = package
                names = [name]
            for name in names:
                if name in seen:
                    continue
                seen.add(name)
                source, filename, is_package = find_module(name)
                if source is None:
                    continue
                if is_package and from_names:
                    # importing from a package, assume the imported names
                    # are modules
                    names += ('{}.{}'.format(name, fn) for fn in from_names)
                    continue
                with source:
                    module_ast = ast.parse(source.read(), filename)
                stack.append((name, module_ast))
                
        elif not _is_admissible_node(script_object):
            raise Exception("Config file '%s' contains unacceptable statements" % path_to_config)
```

In case of `from foo import bar` imports, if `foo` is a package then `foo/__init__.py`  is skipped and it is assumed that `bar` will be a module.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> `imp.find_module()` is deprecated for Python 3 code. On Python 3 you would use [`importlib.util.find_spec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec) to get the module loader spec, and then use the [`ModuleSpec.origin` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec.origin) to get the filename. `importlib.util.find_spec()` knows how to handle packages.